# How to adjust screen vertically in bottom tabbar transitions?

Tags: flutter, dart

Previously, I was adjusting the screen vertically in menu transitions using the bottom Tabbar onTap function. On the selected menu page, I added a button for screen rotations in nested screens and everything was working fine. For a reason I don't know why, if I add this feature to the bottom Tabbar onTap function, the screen is forced to portrait mode again. Can not stay in landscape mode. Screen rotation does not work. What could be the problem?

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

 await SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
    DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
  ]);
}
```

This is the onTap Function for rotate screen vertically again bottomTabbar navigations:

```
//rotate to portrait if necessary tab

onTapFunction(BuildContext context, TabsRouter tabsRouter) {
    if (tabsRouter.activeIndex == 0 ||
        tabsRouter.activeIndex == 2 ||
        tabsRouter.activeIndex == 3) {
      SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
        DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
      ]);
    }

    return tabsRouter.setActiveIndex;
  }
```

This is the screen rotate button on nested pages:

```
//Change rotate button according to screen orientation

 MediaQuery.of(context).orientation == Orientation.landscape
            ? IconButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
                    DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
                  ]);
                },
                icon: const Icon(
                  FontAwesomeIcons.arrowRotateLeft,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              )
            : IconButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
                    DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
                    DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft
                  ]);
                },
                icon: const Icon(
                  FontAwesomeIcons.arrowRotateRight,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
```